# Manifold, exist smooth nonnegative function with regular value at 0?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

If $X$ is any manifold with boundary, then does there exist a smooth nonnegative function $f$ on $X$, with a regular value at $0$, such that $\partial X = f^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: Yes. Pick a function that's $(m,t) \mapsto t$ on a collar neighborhood $M \times [0,\varepsilon)$ of the boundary. Interpolate between this and a function that's $1$ on the rest of the manifold with a partition of unity.

Comment: Choose a (smooth) metric on $X$ and define $f(x)$ to be the distance of $x$ from the boundary.

Comment: @PeterFranek: The distance function generally won't be smooth everywhere. But you can smooth it out using a partition of unity or bump function, as suggested by Mike Miller.

Comment: @JackLee Right, thank you. But $f(x)=\varphi(d(x))$ would be probably ok, if $d$ is the distance function and $\varphi: [0,\infty)\to [0,1]$ is smooth, nondecreasing, $\varphi(0)=0$, $\varphi'(0)>0$ and $\varphi[\epsilon,\infty)=1$ for $\epsilon$ small enough.